# VS Code Jupyter Extension: Run my notebooks on a Spark cluster?

Tags: python, apache-spark, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

1. I am an extreme beginner and I like to write Python code using the Jupyter extension for VS Code.
2. I recently started using Azure DataBricks, where my notebooks seem to be running on remote Spark clusters.
3. I would like to be able to have the same experience as the Jupyter extension for VS Code, while running my notebooks on remote Spark clusters.
4. **Is there a way that I can do #3 with other types of Spark clusters?** (Ideally I would like to do this with arbitrary Spark clusters.)

Question #4 depends on premises 1-3, which may be wrong or misleading.

I might not be explaining that correctly. I think I'm looking for something in VS Code analogous to what [JupyterLab Integration](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/12/03/jupyterlab-databricks-integration-bridge-local-and-remote-workflows.html) does for JupyterLab:

> JupyterLab Integration, on the other hand, keeps notebooks locally but  runs all code on the remote cluster if a remote kernel is selected. This  enables your local JupyterLab to run single node data science notebooks  (using pandas, scikit-learn, etc.) on a remote environment maintained  by Databricks or to run your deep learning code on a remote Databricks  GPU machine.

But JupyterLab Integration seems to rely partially on SSH, so maybe there is a way to achieve part of this functionality outside of JupyterLab just by using SSH?